# sqlalchemy random error Exception during reset or similar - no impact on functionality

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an application running and from time to time this stack trace shows in console. However the app continues to run smoothly. Anyway, I don't really like this kind of unpredictable behavior in the app. Can I avoid such error messages? All queries are returned with correct data, updates work fine. No idea why this message keeps popping in logs.

```
Exception during reset or similar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 663, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _reset
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 631, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

This is how I create session and query example:

```
engine = create_engine(
    settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
    pool_pre_ping=True,
    echo=False,
    connect_args={"connect_timeout": 30},
    pool_size=20,
    max_overflow=100,
)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(expire_on_commit=True, autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
```

Query example:

```
def get_user_name(username: str, s=None) -> str:
    if s is None:
        s = SessionLocal()
    try:
        user_obj = s.query(User).filter_by(username=username)
        if len(list(user_obj)) < 1:
            return username
        return user_obj.first().first_name
    except Exception as ex:
        s.rollback()
        logger.exception(f"Failed while Error : {ex}")
```

Comment: Are there any corresponding entries in the PostgreSQL server's logs?

Comment: Certainly this is a database issue which is causing your error in connection. It looks like this error is being "surfaced" by `pool_pre_ping`, which basically is periodically validating your connection pool _(the error would happen anyways, so removing that won't fix)_. My guess is that your database is terminating connections, or your connections are going stale. More context is needed before we can diagnose/solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You actually do want these messages. They state that your parameter `pool_pre_ping=True` works as intended. It is in the nature of the thing that it is unpredictable behavior, as it is handling exactly those unpredictable moments.

I guess you could just try wrap the thing so it does not pop up in your console:

```
try:
  <connect to db>
except psycopg2.OperationalError:
  <log to file>
```